# Can we generate CPP files out of WINRT/header files?

Tags: visual-c++, windows-runtime, c++-winrt

I see that we've a bunch of header files and references(winmd) ,in windows 10 SDK.  Is there any way I can generate cpp files as well out of these so that I can compile all of them together and create a library out of this ?

Basically, what I want is : I do not want to include the publicly available WINRT header files inside my app directly. Instead, I want to create a WINRT library with all the  WINRT definitions which can be referred/linked to in my app. I'll expose the required definitions via some subset of header files.

Let me know if this is possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The header files generated from .winmd files heavily rely on templates. You cannot (easily) compile templates into a library.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the cppwinrt.exe tool that ship in the Windows SDK to generate your own headers that you can then include in your project.